# Use of undeclared identifier 'FBSDKAppEventNameFBSDKSmartLoginService'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm getting this bizarre error in Xcode when trying to compile the app on working on that says "Use of undeclared identifier 'FBSDKAppEventNameFBSDKSmartLoginService.'" The weird part is that I only get the error after I installed GoogleAnalytics. I'm using pods for this app and I think that that might have something to do with this error. I'm not updating any other dependencies, just installing Google Analytics. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

Do check if in `.plist` file, `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` has `fbauth2` & `fbapi` keys